# Query a dictionary of hashsets

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashset

Given a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` and a certain string, how do I check if all the values (hashsets) in the dictionary contain that string? I need to do it as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string searchFor = //
bool allContain = dict.Values.All(s => s.Contains(searchFor));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ: (O(n))

```
dictionary.Values.All(set => set.Contains(str))
```